# What are the possible OpCodes for the last instruction of a method?

Tags: c#, .net, cil, il, opcode

In .net what are the possible OpCodes that can exist as the last instruction of a method.

At the moment I know that it can be

- Ret http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ret.aspx
- Throw http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.throw.aspx

But is it possible for it to be any other opcodes? And if so what code (prefer c#) would produce them?

By "Last" I mean "the final OpCode defined in the method body"

Comment: By "last", do you mean the final opcode defined in the method body, or do you mean the last opcode executed? (a method doesn't need to exit from the bottom)

Comment: @MarcGravell "the final opcode defined in the method body". clarified in the question

Comment: Cool, then I suspect the comment I added to Frederic's post applies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `throw` can be the last opcode in a method, chances are that [`jmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.jmp) also qualifies.

Also, if we consider a recursive method whose exit condition is not located at the end, <strike>the last opcode *might* be a [`call`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call) or [`tail.call`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.tailcall) instead of a `ret`.</strike>

*Update:* Well, no, it won't. As Marc Gravell rightfully points out in his comment, the documentation for `tail.call` says:

> The stack must be empty except for the arguments being transferred by
>   the following call. The instruction following the call instruction
>   must be a `ret`.

*Update 2:* Unconditional branch opcodes like [`br`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.br) and [`br.s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.br_s) may also be the last instructions of a method, if its exit point occurs earlier (thanks again Marc).

Comment: "call" would still need a ret after it, iirc; tail.call I'm less sure about (update: "The instruction following the call instruction must be a ret", from the tail page). I think "jmp" is valid, though.

Comment: Two more to replace the 2 I killed: unconditional branch: `br` and `br.s` (with the method *exiting* higher up) - depending on the meaning of "last" (I'll ask the OP)